# "Best-crafted" or "most well-crafted"?

Tags: word-choice, superlative-degree

*This is their best-crafted song.*
*That is the most well-crafted passage in the book.*

Simple question here. Is any more correct, or incorrect perhaps? Which seeems to be used more?

Comment: "Most well" is "best". But take a look at [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+well-crafted%2Cbest-crafted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: What a "turn" from early 2000s on. I also put "-written" instead: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+well-written%2Cbest-written&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: "Best-crafted" is correct English, but "most well-crafted" is more likely to sound familiar to most English speakers.

Comment: NGram is interesting but no idea what conclusion should be drawn. I guess either is OK.